# How to convert number systems on Sharp calculator if the number has decimal points, for example 3B.254?

Tags: software

I would like convert decimal octal numbers on sharp EL-531TH (or any other) caclulator but when I enable the octal or any other non-decimal function, the decimal key or dot key (marked with red) is disabled.

How to do that conversion with a decimal point on a Sharp calculator? When I want to convert, for example 35.685 (10) to (16) it ignores the decimal point and gives a non-accurate result.

So, more in detail: How to convert with decimal point on Sharp calculator from:

**1) Hexadecimal to:** (Example: 3B.254 from...)

- hexadecimal to octal,
- hexadecimal to decimal,
- hexadecimal to binary.

**2) Decimal to:** (Example: 23.7956 from...)

- decimal to hexadecimal,
- decimal to octal,
- decimal to binary.

**3) Octal to:** (Example: 30.6121 from...)

- octal to hexadecimal,
- octal to decimal,
- octal to binary.

**4) Binary to:** (Example: 10011.011001 from...)

- binary to hexadecimal,
- binary to decimal,
- binary to octal?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you consulted this (page 26ff) ? https://global.sharp/contents/calculator/support/guidebook/documents/OperationGuide_EL531TH.pdf

Comment: @MPIchael Unfortunately, I can't find what I'm looking for on the link you provided.

Comment: Have you considered (for example) converting 3B2 from hex to decimal and then dividing the result by 16 to account for the "hexadecimal" point?

Comment: @BrianBorchers 3B2 (16) is 964 (10) an 946:16=59.125. So the result would be 946.125? That is correct, but what about transforming for example 3F3.563 (16) to decimal? And then decimal to binary? Because if I type 946.125 (10) to convert to hexadecimal, it ignores the decimals. In this case it gives the result 3B2, which is not a accurate result.

Comment: Sorry- it wasn't clear to me that the original hex number was 3B.254.  Convert 3B254 from hex to decimal, then divide by 16 three times.

Comment: Thank you. That works. Bu what about converting 3B.254 (16) to octal? What algorithm would be in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the calculator supports converting integers to another base, you can always multiply your number with the base N times (with it's base) to obtain a integer, convert, then divide.
*Note: This assumes the calculator can at least divide in hex, octal and binary. Without this, converting from decimal is going to be tricky.*

Thee different bases we'll need to conveniently convert between these 4 bases:

$$\begin{aligned}
10_{16} = 16_{10} &= 20_{8} = 10000_{2}\\
A_{16} = 10_{10} &= 12_{8} = 1010_{2}\\
8_{16} = 8_{10} &= 10_{8} = 1000_{2}\\
2_{16} = 2_{10} &= 2_{8} = 10_{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

You'll take your number, multiple it by it's base N times for N digits of precision, convert, then divide by the same number (in the new base)

## Hexadecimal 3B.254

Starting with $3B.254_{16}$, we start by scaling it up by $10_{16}^3$ and we of course obtain $3B254_{16}$. We can then convert it to each base:
$$
3B254_{16} = 242260_{10} = 731124_8 = 111011001001010100_2
$$
and then divide by the same scaling factor we used earlier: $10_{16}^3 = 16_{10}^3 = 20_8^3 = 10000_2^3$

$$
\begin{aligned}
242260_{10} / 16_{10}^3 &= 59.1455078125_{10}\\
731124_8 / 20_8^3 &= 73.1124_8\\
111011001001010100_2 / 10000_2^3 &= 111011.0010010101_2
\end{aligned}
$$

Since hex, octal and binary shares the prime factor 2 in their base making it easier to convert and we can take some shortcuts: $16^3 = 8^4 = 2^{12}$, 3 digits in base 16 is 4 digits in base 8 which is 12 digits in base 2.

To illustrate, I will complete your examples using this method.

## Decimal 23.7956

Convert as integer:
$$
237956_{10} = 3A184_{16} = 720604_8 = 111010000110000100_2
$$

and dividing by $10_10^4$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
3A184_{16} / A_{16}^4 &= 17.cbac710cb295_{16}\\
720604_8 / 12_8^4 &= 27.627261610313_8\\
111010000110000100_2 / 1010_2^4 &= 10111.110010111_2
\end{aligned}
$$

## Octal 30.6121

Convert as integer:
$$
306121_8 = 101457_{10} = 18c51_{16} = 11000110001010001_2
$$

dividing by $10_8^4$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
101457_{10} / 8_{10}^4 &= 24.769775390625_{10}\\
18c51_{16} / 8_{16}^4 &= 18.c51_{16}\\
11000110001010001_2 / 1000_2^4 &= 11000.11000101_2
\end{aligned}
$$

## Binary 10011.011001

Convert as integer
$$
10011011001_2 = 1241_{10} = 4d9_{16} = 2331_8
$$

and dividing by $10_2^6$
$$
\begin{aligned}
1241_{10} / 2_{10}^6 &= 19.3900625_{10}\\
4d9_{16} / 2_{16}^6 &= 13.64_{16}\\
2331_8 / 2_8^6 &= 23.31_8\\
\end{aligned}
$$

(Disclaimer: Lots of numbers to copy here, I may have made some typos)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.                        
What calculator did you use for these calculations? I tried on my (I have the model from the picture) for example converting 2.3 (8) to hexadecimal. So that would be 17 (16)/ 8 (16) an the answer would be 2.6 (16) but my calculator gives and answer 2. It ignores the decimal point and gives a non-accurate result. I am interested in buying a new caclulator that is why I am asking for that.

Comment: @Alezigl I just used my computer, though i followed the procedure above and only converted them as integers: $2.3_8 = 23_8 / 10_8 = 13_{16} / 8_{16} = 2.6_{16}$. The entire point of my answer is how to do this with just integers.

Comment: So, the answer on the question: is it possible to to such convertions on handheld scientific calculator is no?

Comment: If you can do division indifferent bases, yes, by following the algorithm laid out. 
If you stick to hex, octal, and binary and stick to 3:4:12 decimal digit ratio, then you can do the division in your head, since it's just division by "10": $10_{16}^3 = 10_{8}^4 = 10_{2}^12$.  Again your example: $2.3_8 = 23000_8 / 10000_8 = 2600_{16} / 1000_{16} = 2.6_{16}$, using the calculator for the step $23000_8 = 2600_{16}$. If your calculator can't do division in other bases, converting from decimal to hex/oct/binary is not possible.